# Define the value of a constant or variable as the name of the constant or variable without an assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a dreadfully long constants file that looks something like this:

```
export const AUTH_REQUEST = 'AUTH_IN_PROGRESS';
export const AUTH_SUCCESS = 'AUTH_SUCCESS';
export const AUTH_FAIL = 'AUTH_FAIL';
export const AUTH_TERMINATE = 'AUTH_TERMINATE';
export const AUTH_REDIRECT = 'AUTH_REDIRECT';
```

....and so on.

Is it possible to declare a variable / constant / etc. to have the same name as the variable itself?

Or...is there a data structure that would allow for something like this?

`const AUTH = {'TERMINATE', 'REDIRECT'}` ...etc

So you would have `AUTH.TERMINATE` with a value of `TERMINATE`.

My backup solution is to do something like this: `const AUTH = keyObj(['TERMINATE', 'SUCCESS'])`.

That function would look something like this:

`let keyObj = (vals)=>{
  let obj = {};
  vals.forEach((v)=>{ obj[v]=v; });
  return obj;
}`

Comment: why not collect them in an object?

Comment: There's nothing built into the language for that, no.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's what the function at the bottom does

Comment: Note that your very first example doesn't match what you say you want to do - the value is different to the name?  Also one of the reasons for using constants is that if the value changes, you only change it in one place.  If you had a way to auto map names to values, if the value changes, that implies a name change, which implies all your code breaks because the constant isn't there anymore.  This shortcut seems nonsensical...

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's why it's a constant. It's immuatable once declared.

Comment: I mean change as in a few months down the line you decide it needs to be different, not a change during runtime.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the idea is to come up with something that doesn't need to be changed, a pattern that can be applied to hundreds of constants, consistently.

Comment: @Pointy Good point, fixed =)

Comment: I realise that.  But lets say you end up with a way to autogenerate them so `AUTH.TERMINATE` is `"TERMINATE"`.  All your code references `AUTH.TERMINATE`.  2 months down the line you realise it shouldn't be `"TERMINATE"` but `"EXTERMINATE"` instead (perhaps the 3rd party you're integrating with makes a breaking change - these things happen).  Your auto-gen code now creates `AUTH.EXTERMINATE` but all your other code that uses it is now using the non-existent `AUTH.TERMINATE`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Recursive search / replace?

Comment: Yuck.  I'd rather have the "dreadfully long constants file" doing it's job properly in the first place.  If it's really that annoying, write some code to generate the file itself.  It's a one off cost, once you have it it's done.

Comment: `[].map` creates a new array. If you don't want that array, use `[].forEach` instead of `[].map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

1. Create an array with the desired strings.
2. Use [`[].reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build an object which has these strings as property names and values, passing an empty object as initial value. [`[].forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) may work too.
3. [Freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object.

```js
var strings = ['a', 'b'],
    obj = Object.create(null);
strings.forEach(function(str) {
  obj[str] = str;
});
Object.freeze(obj);
```

Minifying in a single statement,

```js
Object.freeze(['a','b'].reduce((o,s) => (o[s]=s, o), Object.create(null)));
```

Comment: Here's what I ended up with: ```let consts = function(){
  return Object.freeze(Array.from(arguments).reduce((o,s) => (o[s]=s, o), Object.create(null)));
}.bind(null);```

Comment: Consider using rest arguments instead of `Array.from(arguments)` and `.bind(null)` seems a bit useless: `let consts = function(...args){ return Object.freeze(args.reduce((o,s) => (o[s]=s, o), Object.create(null))); }`

Comment: even better =). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper function:

```
function consts() {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(o, c) {
    o[c] = c;
    return o;
  }, {});
}
```

Then:

```
var AUTH = consts("TERMINATE", "REDIRECT");
```

*edit* — if you want it to be immutable, you could make sure the properties are created that way:

```
function consts() {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(o, c) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, c, {
      value: c, enumerable: true
    });
    return o;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: @CalvinFroedge note that `Array.from()` is ES2015 but it's super-easy to work around that.

Comment: Yea, everything is being transpiled anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to declare a variable / constant / etc. to have the same name as the variable itself?

If you're in strict mode (and you might have to be to use `const`), I'm pretty sure there's no way to dynamically populate the JavaScript namespace. Which is effectively what you're asking so, no, sorry. Other answers here are dynamically adding properties to an object, which is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package that does that. https://www.npmjs.com/package/keymirror

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got it right, but with this:

```
const types = ['SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'TERMINATE'];
const AUTH  = {};

for (let type of types) {
  AUTH[type] = type;
}
```

You'll get `AUTH.TERMINATE` with a value of string `"TERMINATE"` etc.